# Hexdump not displaying international characters

Tags: python, unicode, hexdump

I am trying to decode network data where I have set the `password` as `pas$w0rd@1ħ213₹`.

I would like to see this entire password string in the output of hexdump but it seems its limited to ASCII range of characters only.

Here is an example output using Linux' hexdump:

```
hexdump hexd.hex -C -L                          
00000000  18 03 02 40 00 02 ff ff  70 6f 74 61 74 6f 45 43  |...@....potatoEC|
00000010  4f 44 45 43 4f 44 45 43  4f 44 45 43 4f 44 45 43  |ODECODECODECODEC|
00000020  4f 44 45 43 4f 44 45 43  4f 44 45 00 00 02 00 2f  |ODECODECODE..../|
00000030  01 00 00 05 00 0f 00 01  01 0a 55 73 65 72 2d 41  |..........User-A|
00000040  67 65 6e 74 3a 20 63 75  72 6c 2f 37 2e 38 36 2e  |gent: curl/7.86.|
00000050  30 0d 0a 41 63 63 65 70  74 3a 20 2a 2f 2a 0d 0a  |0..Accept: */*..|
00000060  43 6f 6e 74 65 6e 74 2d  4c 65 6e 67 74 68 3a 20  |Content-Length: |
00000070  34 35 0d 0a 43 6f 6e 74  65 6e 74 2d 54 79 70 65  |45..Content-Type|
00000080  3a 20 61 70 70 6c 69 63  61 74 69 6f 6e 2f 78 2d  |: application/x-|
00000090  77 77 77 2d 66 6f 72 6d  2d 75 72 6c 65 6e 63 6f  |www-form-urlenco|
000000a0  64 65 64 0d 0a 0d 0a 75  73 65 72 6e 61 6d 65 3d  |ded....username=|
000000b0  75 73 65 72 6e 61 6d 65  26 70 61 73 73 77 6f 72  |username&passwor|
000000c0  64 3d 70 61 73 24 77 30  72 64 40 31 c4 a7 32 31  |d=pas$w0rd@1..21|
000000d0  33 e2 82 b9 fc f3 ca d2  0a 49 8b 0a b3 47 04 f8  |3........I...G..|
```

The same goes with python3's hexdump library:

```
000000A0: 64 65 64 0D 0A 0D 0A 75  73 65 72 6E 61 6D 65 3D  ded....username=
000000B0: 75 73 65 72 6E 61 6D 65  26 70 61 73 73 77 6F 72  username&passwor
000000C0: 64 3D 70 61 73 24 77 30  72 64 40 31 C4 A7 32 31  d=pas$w0rd@1..21
000000D0: 33 E2 82 B9 FC F3 CA D2  0A 49 8B 0A B3 47 04 F8  3........I...G..
```

However, my terminal can certainly decode these characters.
Here is the output of `sed` that prints all printable characters:

```
❯ sed 's/[^[:print:]]//g' hexd.hex       
@��potatoECODECODECODECODECODECODECODE/
User-Agent: curl/7.86.0
Accept: */*
Content-Length: 45
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

username=username&password=pas$w0rd@1ħ213₹����
I�
```

My Locale is set to `en_US.UTF-8`

How do I use hexdump or any alternative that prints the hex and the corresponding Unicode characters on the terminal?
I am looking for a way on both the terminal or python

Comment: A hexdump inherently displays data byte-by-byte - but in UTF-8 encoding, all non-ASCII characters occupy more than one byte.

Comment: Unicode numbers are just that, numbers, not bytes.  They have to be encoded to be represented as one or more bytes per Unicode number.  How would you want the *byte* offset and character it represents displayed for a Unicode character that can't be represented in a single byte?

Answer (score 0):

As some people already have pointed out in the comments, this does not really work because a hexdump just gives you the bytes. For ASCII characters this is not a problem as they are one byte large, but all non-ASCII characters are larger than a byte and thus get split up when being displayed using a hexdump.

You can see this happening in your hexdump aswell: The part where the hbar should be has two dots in the hexdump and not just one.

However depending on what you really want to do in the end I might have an solution for you. In Visual Studio Code's hexdump you can mark more than one byte and the data inspector will show you the character in different encodings:

[image: VSC Hexdump]